# Why cannot call constexpr member function by pointer?

Tags: c++, clang

See the code below, for clang (14.0.6), almost all member function calling via pointer were compile-error, except calling by `0x0`. But GCC would accept more.

It seems lacks useful information on cppreference.(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression)

How can I call constexpr member function and constexpr conversion function by pointer?

```cpp
#include <memory>

struct MyType {
    constexpr static bool fixed() { return true; }
    constexpr bool dyn() const { return true; }

    constexpr MyType() {}
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<MyType> uptr;
    MyType inst;
    MyType *ptr;
    MyType &ref = inst;

    static_assert( (*(const MyType* const)0).fixed() );  //clang_Pass!
    static_assert( (*(const MyType* const)1).fixed() );  //clang_error

    static_assert(uptr->fixed());  //error
    static_assert(uptr->dyn());    //error

    static_assert(inst.fixed());   //Pass!
    static_assert(inst.dyn());     //Pass!

    static_assert(ptr->fixed());   //GCC_Pass! clang_error
    static_assert(ptr->dyn());     //error

    static_assert(ref.fixed());    //GCC_Pass! clang_error
    static_assert(ref.dyn());      //error

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good question, although it might be worth removing all that undefined behaviour with uninitialized pointers.

Answer (score 3):

```
(*(const MyType* const)0).fixed()
```

Has defined behavior and is a constant expression, because `0` is a null pointer constant, so that this resolves to a `static_cast`, not `reinterpret_cast`. Therefore none of the disqualifiers in [[expr.const]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5) apply. Clang is correct to accept the `static_assert` and GCC should also accept it. This wouldn't work if you retrieved `0` from a variable or anything but using the literal `0` directly in the cast.

```
(*(const MyType* const)1).fixed()
```

Behavior of the cast is implementation-defined, but in either case, it uses `reinterpret_cast` which is not allowed in constant expressions.

```
uptr->fixed()
```

You default-initialized `uptr` which means it is empty. `operator->` of `std::unique_ptr` has a pre-condition that it is not empty. Therefore this has undefined behavior. It is unspecified whether library undefined behavior causes an otherwise constant expression to not be a constant expression. So it is unspecified whether compilation will fail with the `static_assert`.

```
uptr->dyn()
```

Same.

```
inst.fixed()
```

That has defined behavior and is a constant expression, because none of the disqualifiers in [[expr.const]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5) apply.

```
inst.dyn()
```

Same.

```
ptr->fixed()
```

That's UB for dereferencing a pointer with indeterminate value and therefore also not a constant expression. GCC is wrong to accept it in the `static_assert`.

```
ptr->dyn()
```

Same.

```
ref.fixed()
```

Defined behavior, but not a constant expression until recently because `ref` isn't *usable in constant expressions*, as it hasn't been initialized with to refer to an object of static storage duration. That's specifically a requirement when using a reference's name in a constant expression. (see [expr.const]/5.12)

This was recently improved in the standard as a defect report against older versions, but compilers haven't implemented it yet as far as I know. I think (should probably check) this should work with that defect report implemented. I guess GCC passing it was previously a bug, not due to implementation of the DR.

```
ref.dyn()
```

Same.

> How can I call constexpr member function and constexpr conversion function by pointer?

The pointer variable needs to be marked `constexpr` and initialized to refer to an object with static storage duration or the pointer's lifetime must start during evaluation of the constant expression. In the case of `fixed` it should also be fine to mark the pointer `constexpr` and initialize it with a null pointer constant, preferably `nullptr` over a literal `0`.

Comment: Thank you but the problem still existed : I try to make define to `constexpr const MyType * const ptr = nullptr;` , then the static_assert of `ptr` keep as-is on clang but all passed on GCC.

Comment: @vrqq Can't reproduce: `fixed` works on both as I expect (https://godbolt.org/z/cW1a96qP1) and `dyn` doesn't work on Clang as I expect (https://godbolt.org/z/To4nr1doW). I think it is wrong that GCC accepts the latter.